# Windows 10 symbolic link: bash vs cmd

Tags: windows-10, bash, cmd.exe, symbolic-link

I have a single bash script that I use to launch many programs.
I called this script `launcher.sh`
To use it, I create a symbolic link named `myprog` pointing to `launcher.sh`.

While in BASH shell (MSYS2/MINGW64)
inside `launcher.sh`, I determine the name of the "script itself" and I get "myprog" and, so, I can proceed accordingly.

While in CMD shell
inside `launcher.sh`, I determine the name of the "script itself" and I get "launcher" and, so, I don't know what program I am supposed to launch.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this using normal .bat files it works fine, and running WSL bash on .sh files works fine, but launching the file using git-bash did not work. So, I think the answer is to use either .bat or WSL for .sh in Windows.
To test I used test.bat with echo %0 and test.sh with echo $0, and then created symlinks with mklink, and checked the responses when calling the scripts directly and with the symlinks. I did not test hard links or junctions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, basically, you confirmed what I am experiencing. But, at this point, I won't be using WSL (I don't think IT supports it, yet) and *.bat is not an option...I am looking for a way to re-use a lot of bash scripts and a bunch of other things on Windows that I have been using on Linux...I don't want to have to re-write and debug everything, again...most everything is working out just fine, just run into this symlink discrepancy.

Comment: I just tested this from within git-bash and it works fine that way, so I believe the issue has to do with Windows doing the symlink resolution for you prior to starting up git-bash. So, if you stay in bash when working with the scripts, it might work. While that's not what you were originally looking to do, maybe it's better than nothing?

Comment: Well, well...I just noticed that PowerShell fully supports symbolic links and they behave just as in Linux and MinGW.   Now, I need to find out how to do "Environment Modules" in PowerShell and I will be set.